# how to update a single contact's group membership with Google Contact API and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, api, contacts

I want to retrieve a specific contact, and update its group membership.  I already know the self link of the contact.  To get the specific contact, the developer's guide says to do this:

//The example assumes the ContactRequest object (cr) is already set up.

```
Contact c = cr.Retrieve<Contact>("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/liz%40gmail.com/full/12345");
```

but when I compile this, I get an error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Google.Contacts.Contact'

If I change it to:

```
Contact c = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(new Uri("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/liz%40gmail.com/full/12345"));
```

then it compiles, and seems to retrieve okay, but I'm unable to update the contact's group membership:

```
c.GroupMembership.Add(member2);
cr.Update(c);
```

as the cr.Update(c) line throws a GDataRequestException (400 Bad Request) with a response string of:

"Group membership information not supported"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong...

When retrieving the contact, I was using the "Id" property, instead of the "Self" property.

The "Id" property has "base" projection, while the "Self" property has "Full" projection.

Once I switched to using "Self" it worked properly.